# Packet organization for similar but different type messages

Tags: java, libgdx, packet, kryonet

In a game, the server might have to send the client a packet with info to, lets say, add an Enemy. The data to add such an enemy might be similar to every enemy (position, id...) but there is a need to distinguish which enemy it is. Is it the zombie? A werewolf? Well.

I can remember two ways of doing this:

1 - Create an Enum.
 So I could have an Enum with every type of enemy there is, and in my Packet, I would send that type.
**Pros:** Only one Packet to add several types of enemies, only one method to handle the receiving of it.

**Cons:** Everytime I want to add a new enemy, i must create a new entry on the enum,  and the method which receives will most likely be an annoying big switch-case.

2 - Create a packet per enemy, each with a different "handle" method
**Pros:** It "seems" more organized since each element has an assigned packet and method, and no need to add an entry to the enum (although id need to add a new handle method so.... yeah.)

**Cons:** Many enemies mean many packets, which mean many handle methods, which might be a mess.

So, basicly, tl:dr, either i have a "PacketAddEnemy" with an enum like EnemyType and a few switch-cases, or I have "PacketAddZombie", "PacketAddWerewolf", etc, but end up with a spam of packets and methods.

I prefer the first option, but I dislike both. I wonder if there's interesting alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to handle this. My favorite way to handle this is similar to option one that you posted. Where each Entity has a unique type ID. Instead of one long switch statement to say create entities, you could instead use a more [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) based approach. It's a slightly slower way but it does provide for a very nice and clean interface.

Just remember that there are a lot of ways to handle this, and this is just my preferred way. Each game handles this differently and you really just have to go with something you like.

**Example:**

```
public enum EntityIDs {

    Zombie( EntityZombie.class ),
    Werewolf( EntityWerewolf.class );
    // And so on for all of your entities

    public Class< ? extends Entity > entityClass;

    private EntityIDs( Class< ? extends Entity > cl ) {
        this.entityClass = cl;
    }

    public static Entity createEntity( int id ) {
        Class< ? extends Entity > cl = EntityIDs.values()[ id ].entityClass;

        return cl.newInstance();
    }
}
```

You would then receive a type ID from the server and common data, such as location. That ID could be the ordinal of the Entity Type, or some other way you decide to map it to their type. You can then use the entityClass field to reflectively create your entities. Of course this requires that you still list out every entity in an enum, but creating a new one is as simple as a single line. This does require that all Entities subclass a common super class, such as Entity in this case. It also requires that each Entity subclass have a common constructor, usually just a default constructor with initialization done after construction.

Having a common super class does simplify part of your problem. You would put all common data, such as location, inside the super class. When you want to move an entity you would not need to care what type of entity it is, you would only need to know which entity and where it was moving.

```
World world = ...;
Entity entity = world.getEntity( entityId );
if( entity != null ) {
    entity.move( newX, newY );
}
```

Again I would like to reiterate this is only one way to do it and is in no way the only way to do this. This can easily be expanded to many different solutions that really depend on your preferences. It is in no way a complete example, but just a general idea of my preferred solution.

This does come with performance costs because reflection is not very fast. It usually consists of several more method invocations for each invocation. You could change this to use a factory pattern instead where each Entity type has an EntityCreator that is responsible for creating each Entity.